# How to change job/stage description in web UI?

Tags: apache-spark

When I run a job on Apache Spark, the web UI gives a view similar to this:

[image]

While this is incredibly useful for me as a developer to see where things are, I think the line numbers in the stage description would be not quite as useful for my support team.  To make their job easier, I would like to have the ability to provide a bespoke name for each stage of my job, as well as for the job itself, like so:

[image]

Is this something that can be done in Spark?  If so, how would I do so?

Comment: You may also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39123314/1305344

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives the same description to every stage of a given job.  I want to be able to give different stages different names.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something but isn't the ability to set stage descriptions pretty important to users of the web UI? The defaults of relying on the operation name - "map", "forEachPartition" etc are hardly useful without a good knowledge of the codebase. Maybe I'm doing Spark wrong?

Comment: I'd argue as the concepts of jobs, stages, tasks are fairly low-level and Spark developers know about them after they're fine with the codebase (they usually developed themselves). So, they know where `map`, `foreachPartition` or such are in the code, but not necessarily how they translate to jobs, stages and tasks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's where one of the very uncommon features of Spark Core called **local properties** applies so well.

Spark SQL uses it to group different Spark jobs under a single structured query so you can use SQL tab and navigate easily.

You can control local properties using [SparkContext.setLocalProperty](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@setLocalProperty(key:String,value:String):Unit):

> Set a local property that affects jobs submitted from this thread, such as the Spark fair scheduler pool. User-defined properties may also be set here. These properties are propagated through to worker tasks and can be accessed there via org.apache.spark.TaskContext#getLocalProperty.

web UI uses two local properties:

- `callSite.short` in Jobs tab (and is exactly what you want)
- `callSite.long` in Job Details page.

### Sample Usage

```
scala> sc.setLocalProperty("callSite.short", "callSite.short")

scala> sc.setLocalProperty("callSite.long", "this is callSite.long")

scala> sc.parallelize(0 to 9).count
res2: Long = 10
```

And the result in web UI.

[image: Jobs tab in web UI with callSite.short]

Click a job to see the details where you can find the longer call site, i.e. `callSite.long`.

[image: Job details in web UI with callSite.long]

Here comes the Stages tab.

[image: Stages tab in web UI]

Comment: Because I'm running a job that requires multiple stages, I require a different description for each stage.  This answer puts the same description in every stage, which is actually a step back from where I wish to go.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I don't think it's possible to have different names per stage since they could not necessarily map nicely to your business stages and moreover since you don't have access to stages whatsoever. You can influence their number, though.

Comment: Yeah, I've since come to that conclusion, and also decided that getting it at the job level is good enough for us.

Comment: to reset the property back to normal what it would have been as default   sc.setLocalProperty("callSite.short",null)

Comment: For Spark 2.3.1 this property is called `spark.job.description`. Found by diving into source code a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following API(s) to set and unset the stage names.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#setCallSite-java.lang.String-
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#clearCallSite--

Also, Spark supports the concept of Job Groups within the application, following API(s) can be used to set and unset the job group names.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#setJobGroup-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#clearJobGroup--

The job description within the job group can also be configured using following API.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#setJobDescription-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark, you could use snippet below:

```
sc.setJobDescription('test job')
spark.createDataFrame([(1,)],('Id integer')).show()
```

Official documentation: [setJobDescription](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.setJobDescription.html#pyspark.SparkContext.setJobDescription)