# Not possible to set job description in spark streamingContext?

Tags: spark-streaming

I am try to do

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("appName")
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
sc.setJobGroup("jobName", "job description")
val ssc: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
```

And it seems that setJobGroup is never working. I saw there is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10649, which it seems that `StreamingContext` overwrites information in the `SparkContext`. However `StreamingContext` doesn't provide any method to set Spark job description. I am wondering is there any way to customize job description for Spark streaming job?

Comment: I agree, it seems like the solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903342/how-to-change-job-stage-description-in-web-ui does not work for streaming jobs.