# Is it possible to set Job Description for all actions on some RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm running SparkSession as follows:

```
val query: String = //...
val session = SparkSession.builder
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .getOrCreate()

val iterator = session.sql(query).rdd.toLocalIterator
```

I read [***this answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903496/2786156) and understood that `sc.setLocalProperty("callSite.short", "callSite.short")`. But this is not applicable in my case.

The thing is I dont know which thread will use the `iterator` I got here. Is it possible to set job description to be displayed in ***Spark Web UI*** for all actions on the RDD I got with `session.sql(query).rdd`?

Comment: sc.setJobDescription before hand

Comment: @eliasah This is for `SparkContext`. But I use Hive support to query Hive.

Comment: You are using a regular spark scala app ? you can call the underlying SparkContext with session.sparkContext.