# How to get detailed Information about Spark Stages&Tasks

Tags: apache-spark

I´ve set up an Apache Spark cluster with a master and one Worker and I use Python with Spyder as IDE. Everything works fine so far, but I need detailed Information about the task distribution in the Cluster. I know that there is the Spark Web UI but I would like to have Information directly in my Spyder console. So I mean which part of my code/script is done by which Worker/Master. I think with the python package "socket" and socket.gethostname() it must be possible to get more Information. I really look forward to for an help. 
Here is my code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

#spark = SparkSession \
#    .builder \
#    .appName('weather_data') \
#    .getOrCreate()


spark = SparkSession \
   .builder \
   .appName("weather_data_u") \
   .master('master_ip@...')\
   .getOrCreate()

data.show()
data.printSchema()

data_selected = data\
        .select(data['Date'],
                data['TemperatureHighC'],
                data['TemperatureAvgC'],
                data['TemperatureLowC'],
                data['DewpointHighC'],
                data['DewpointAvgC'],
                data['DewpointLowC'],
                data['HumidityAvg'],
                data['WindSpeedMaxKMH'],
                data['WindSpeedAvgKMH'],
                data['GustSpeedMaxKMH'],
                data['PrecipitationSumCM'])

data_selected.printSchema()
data_selected.show()


f = udf(lambda row: datetime.strptime(row, '%Y-%m-%d'), TimestampType())

data_selected = data_selected\
        .withColumn('date', f(data['Date'].cast(StringType())))\
        .withColumn('t_max', data['TemperatureHighC'].cast(DoubleType()))\
        .withColumn('t_mean', data['TemperatureAvgC'].cast(DoubleType()))\
        .withColumn('t_min', data['TemperatureLowC'].cast(DoubleType()))\
        .withColumn('dew_max', data['DewpointHighC'].cast(DoubleType()))\
        .withColumn('dew_mean', data['DewpointAvgC'].cast(DoubleType()))\
        .withColumn('dew_min', data['DewpointLowC'].cast(DoubleType()))\
        .cache()

 data_selected.show()

t_mean_calculated = data_selected\
.groupBy(F.date_format(data_selected.date, 'M'))\
.agg(F.mean(data_selected.t_max))\
.orderBy('date_format(date, M)')

t_mean_calculated = t_mean_calculated\
.withColumn('month', t_mean_calculated['date_format(date, M)'].cast(IntegerType()))\
.withColumnRenamed('avg(t_max)', 't_max_month')\
.orderBy('month')\
.drop(t_mean_calculated['date_format(date, M)'])\
.select('month', 't_max_month')

t_mean_calculated = t_mean_calculated.collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [reported by **@Jacek Laskowski**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903496/3679900) himself, you can use `Spark`-*Core* **local properties** to modify *job-name* in *web-ui*

- `callSite.short`
- `callSite.long`

---

For instance, my `Spark`-application syncs multiple `MySQL` tables to `S3`, and I set

```
spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("callSite.short", currentTableName)
```

so reflect current table-name in web-ui

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just a little additional question, does it also work with SparkSession instead of SparkContext?

Comment: **@Maik**: *Yes*; In the above `code-snippet`, `spark` in `spark.sparkContext..` is nothing but a reference to `SparkSession` (`Scala` `implicits`)