# Tracing multiple spark sessions in spark application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have a java application. In the java application I have spark context. From spark context I create multiple spark session by doing sparkSession.newSession(). At any given point of time there would be 4-5 sessions running. There will be multiple sql queries and join happening in each session.

But when i look at spark ui, i can see list of spark sql, jobs and stages. I find it very difficult to figure out which jobs are triggered from same session. Is there a way session based observability can be achieved from spark ui? i also tried seeing if we could change the job name to reflect which session it is part of based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903496) answer but apparantly it is setting properties at spark context level which is shared across all the sessions. hence it would not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** web UI no. `SparkListener` yes.

---

Spark's web UI does not show which `SparkSession` a given query was launched from. That's what `SparkListener` is for. You can intercept all the query-related metadata that web UI uses to render the pages.

You can build a more sophisticated web UI-like interface yourself using `SparkListener`.